# Fetch in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise, babeljs

Following code does not work on IE at all.

```js
fetch("{{{LINK TO API}}}", {
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(function(json) {
        // SET VARIABLES
        var seller = json.sellers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(json.sellers.length))];
        
        // INSERT COMPANY LOGO
        companyLogo.src = json.logo_url;

        // INSERT SELLER PROFILES
        document.querySelectorAll("[data-seller-profile]").forEach(wrapper => {
            var innerHTML = "";
            innerHTML += "<img class='hbba-profile-img' src='" + seller.profile_image + "'>";
            innerHTML += "<div class='hbba-desc-wrapper'>";
            innerHTML += "<span class='hbba-desc-name'>" + seller.name + "</span>";
            innerHTML += "<span class='hbba-desc-title'>" + seller.job_title + "</span>";
            innerHTML += "</div>";
            innerHTML += "<div class='hbba-is-active'></div>";
            wrapper.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        });
    });
```

The code is in a Webpack environment and gets complied with @babel/preset-env, as well as @babel/polyfill as `entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/main.js"],`.

Compiled code: `fetch("https://helpbox-by-avense.se/api/company/1/init-info",{headers:{Accept:"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json"}}).then(function(t){return t.json()}).then(function(t){var n=t.sellers[Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(t.sellers.length))];u.src=t.logo_url,document.querySelectorAll("[data-seller-profile]").forEach(function(t){var e="";e+="<img class='hbba-profile-img' src='"+n.profile_image+"'>",e+="<div class='hbba-desc-wrapper'>",e+="<span class='hbba-desc-name'>"+n.name+"</span>",e+="<span class='hbba-desc-title'>"+n.job_title+"</span>",e+="</div>",e+="<div class='hbba-is-active'></div>",t.innerHTML=e})})`

What should be change in order for it to work on IE?

Comment: You might also post the compiled function for reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel not Polyfilling Fetch when using babel-preset-env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908044/babel-not-polyfilling-fetch-when-using-babel-preset-env)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional `fetch` polyfill, Babel won't polyfill this for you, and it won't transpile it either.

https://github.com/github/fetch

Also you don't target any browser in your `.babelrc`, so change it to

```
{
  "presets": [
    [ "@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [ "last 1 version", "ie >= 11" ],
        "node": "6.10",
        "esmodules": true
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Comment: still not working. The `fetch` function works (the request can be found in Network-tab), but the rest of the code is not executed.

Comment: You might also need a `Promise` polyfill then. https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill . Also, please show your `.babelrc`.

Comment: This might be helpful, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470124/promise-is-undefined-in-ie11-using-babel-polyfill/52470159#52470159

Comment: .babelrc: `{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "6.10",
                    "esmodules": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}`

Comment: You're not targetting IE 11, only Node. Added a sample config to fix that.

Comment: Does not seem to work. I will continue to troubleshoot tomorrow, so I will return to you then. Very thankful for your help.

Comment: @MelvinHagberg If my answer solved your problem, remember to mark it correct.